# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-views

Can someone please give me a quick explanation as to what I'm doing wrong when calling about.objects.all() and cv.objects.all(). I tested them in the shell and got the same error.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from resume.models import websites, about, cv
from django.http import HttpResponse


def about_text(request):
    about_text = about.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'text': about_text}

    response = render(request, 'resume.html', context_dict)
    return response 



def cv(request):
    position = cv.objects.all()
    context = {'job': position}

    response = render(request, 'resume.html', context_dict)
    return response
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class cv(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    started = models.DateField()
    ended = models.DateField()
    roles = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.position


class about(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

traceback error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/resume/test

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'resume',
 'blog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\WriteCode\test_env\portfolio\resume\views.py" in cv
  16.   position = cv.objects.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /resume/test
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your view's name and model's name are both `cv`. You need to change your view's name to something else. (maybe `get_all_resumes`)

```
def get_all_resumes(request):
    position = cv.objects.all()
    context = {'job': position}

    response = render(request, 'resume.html', context)
    return response
```

Comment: Of course, knew it was something simple. Thank you ozgurv.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ozgurv's answer, you could also `import resume.models as resume_models` and then refer to the cv class like this: `resume_models.cv.objects.all()`. I don't think it's a better solution but it's worth mentioning.